# Chromium Extensions and Qt QWebView

Tags: qt, google-chrome-extension, chromium, qwebview, browser-addons

Is it possible to integrate chrome extensions (i.e. browser add-ons) with Qt QWebView? If yes, then how? Please could you point me to any docs, tutorials or wiki on the topic?

Answer (score 2):

For the moment, it is not possible. Qt developers don't have this idea in mind for the moment, but maybe for future release. You can read more [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51185), where one of the developers says:

> We don't have any active development on it. One question in particular
>   was that we don't know which extensions our customers would like to
>   use, and for what.

And also:

> We don't have any specific extensions on our roadmap. Looking into
>   what we can easily add and that would be useful is on the roadmap for
>   5.8.